Sqlite database design field value depends on another field value comparable to python dict
I need your suggestion on how to design my sqlite database. I intend to have single Table for my project. In general the table would look like below.



ID
Str_ID
Group
English
German




0x01
ID_YES
Group1
Yes
Ja


0x02
ID_NO
Group1
No
Nein



ID is an INTEGER and primary key. Str_ID, Group, English and German are TEXT.
In my application, the values of fields from English and German column depends on respective field value from Group column.
for example
for Group=Group1 The value of ID-"0x01" and Str_ID-"ID-Yes" for English is "Yes" and German is "Ja"
for Group=Group2 the value of ID-"0x01" and Str_ID-"ID_Yes" for English is "Y" and German is "J"
So, with respect to Group, the value of ID and Str_ID should change.
Symbolically it may be comparable to python dictionary concept
example={ "Group1" : [
        {'ID':0x01, 'Str_ID':"ID_YES", 'English':"Yes", 'German':"Ja"},
        {'ID':0x02, 'Str_ID':"ID_NO", 'English':"No", 'German':"Nein"}
    ],
"Group2" : [ 
        {'ID':0x01, 'Str_ID':"ID_YES", 'English':"Y", 'German':"J"},
        {'ID':0x02, 'Str_ID':"ID_NO", 'English':"N", 'German':"N"}
    ]
}

Is it possible to design this use case from single table ? I highly appreciate your suggestion.
Thanks in advance

I added Group to "PRIMARY KEY". It satisfied my need.
